# How to handle a number input number box without submit button in google apps script webpage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Right now I have a simple input box that I define with a listener:

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('blur', updateMyData);
```

The hope is to update my source database every time someone appears to be done with a box - that is, they've clicked on it, made some changes, and clicked somewhere else.  I don't want to make them click to submit.

The problem is that using "blur" means I capture every time they leave - even if they didn't change anything, while using "change" means I capture every single time they click the up or down arrow in the spinner, which is also not ideal.

I feel like somewhere people have done this before... is there any kind of standard way of handling this?  Or, what's a better way than this?

Comment: You can replace blur with change.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem there is when I click the up/down buttons, that immediately fires that event... and I don't want that...

Comment: If the requirement is not to continually call the handler every change but to rather wait till you "think" user is done, then consider using debounce function.

Comment: Ah, that may be what I'm looking for, thank you

Comment: Ah... cool side effect I didn't plan: the jqueryUI spinner change event has a kind of built-in don't-fire-until-you-stop-changing-things functionality to it.

Comment: This approach is even better!!